# Convert an org table into a tree

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, org-table, property-lists

I have an org table and I will like to convert in into a tree.

So, from:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
|---+---+---|
| a | b | c |
| l | m | n |
```

I will like to go to:

```
* a
  :PROPERTIES:
  :2:        b
  :3:        c
  :END:
* l
  :PROPERTIES:
  :2:        m
  :3:        n
  :END:
```

I tried [this](https://github.com/emacsmirror/org-transform-tree-table). But it did not work.

Also, I am running spacemacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org-transform-table/org-tree-buffer-from-org-table` only works if the table contains outlines, so for your example it would have to look like this:

```
| 1   | 2 | 3 |
|-----+---+---|
| * a | b | c |
| * l | m | n |
```

One way to transform your table is to put point in the first content cell (in your example on `a`) and then type <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(org-table-eval-formula most-positive-fixnum "'(concat \"* \" $1)" nil nil t)` <kbd>RET</kbd>. 
After that, <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-transform-table/org-tree-buffer-from-org-table` <kbd>RET</kbd> should yield the desired result.